# Kepler -Concurrent kernel launches not overlapping

Tags: concurrency, cuda

I am trying to overlap kernel execution on Kepler device, but from NVVP layout it seems that they are not overlapping. here is the code,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
#include<time.h>


#define NY 1024
#define NX 1024
__global__ void kernel1(int j,int *A,int *b)  
{  
int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;  
b[j*NY+i] = A[i*NY+j];  

}  

__global__ void kernel2(int j,int *A,int *b)  
 {  
 int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;  
 for(int time=0;time<100;time++)  
 b[j*NY+i] += 10;  
 }  


 int main()  
 {  
 int nstreams=4;
 int *a, *b;
 struct timeval t1,t2;

cudaMalloc((void**)&a,NX*NY*sizeof(int));
cudaMalloc((void**)&b,NX*NY*sizeof(int));


 cudaStream_t *streams = (cudaStream_t *) malloc(nstreams * sizeof(cudaStream_t));
 for (int i = 0; i < nstreams; i++)
 { 
 cudaStreamCreate(&(streams[i]));
 }

 gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);

 for(int newvar=0;newvar<NX;newvar++)
 {
  kernel1<<<1,NY,0,streams[newvar%nstreams]>>>(newvar,a,b);
 }
 for(int newvar=0;newvar<NX;newvar++)
 {
   kernel2<<<1,NY,0,streams[newvar%nstreams]>>>(newvar,a,b);
 }  
 cudaDeviceSynchronize();  
 gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);

 return 0;

 }
```

Please suggest some tips.
CUDA version 5.5
NVVP version 5.5 Linux machine Ubuntu 12.10

[image]

Comment: "Please suggest some tips.": 1. Use linux instead of windows. 2. Run the cuda [concurrent kernels sample](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#concurrent-kernels) first, and observe it's behavior, before trying your own code.  3. Don't start lines of source code with a backslash character.  Instead, provide a syntactically correct sample that actually compiles.

Comment: 1.It is Linux machine(See Unity GUI on left!) 2. Concurrent kernels sample is working fine and it is overlapping kernel. 3.Backslash remained there while formatting code for asking this question. Code is working fine but something is missing for overlapping .

Comment: So you can't be bothered to edit your code to remove the syntax errors and provide a properly compilable sample?  Voting to close.  SO expects:  "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance. "  You haven't provided an SSCCE.org code.

Comment: @Robert Fixed that. Could you please focus on the problem and tell me what is going wrong?(I bet, I am missing something fundamental hence I am concerned). If you are experienced enough then it could be matter of minute for you to spot the problem. I am new so I am struggling with it.

Comment: Your posted code still does not compile.

Comment: Updated code will compile now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37474/discussion-between-username-4567-and-robert-crovella)

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally I think the problem is that your kernels are not executing long enough.  The execution time of your kernels is a few microseconds, and the kernel launch overhead is also a few microseconds, so you're not seeing any overlap.  By the time the API has completed the setup of the new kernel launch, the previous kernel has finished.

I modified your `kernel1` as follows:

```
__global__ void kernel1(int j,int *A,int *b)  
{  
  int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;  
  for (int q = 0; q < 1000; q++)
    b[j*NY+i] = A[i*NY+j] + q/j;  
}
```

There's nothing magical or special about these modifications, I'm just looking for a way to increase the kernel duration execution (from a few microseconds to a few milliseconds).

With the above changes, I saw good overlap of your `kernel1` in the profiler. 
[image]

I imagine something similar could be done with your `kernel2`.

You should also make sure you have not deselected the "enable concurrent kernel profiling" checkbox when you start a profiling session in `nvvp`.

Comment: Well, I suspected that. Thanks for confirming it.