# How to fix 'Low Kernel Concurrency' warning in Nsight profiler?

Tags: cuda, gpu, profiler, nsight

I am trying to profile a cuda program with kernel calls in Nsight eclipse profiler, But I get this warning : 'Low Kernel Concurrency, the percentage of time when two kernels are being executed in parallel is low'. When I run the program the results show that the Kernels are running in parallel.

I checked for some other simple cuda codes and the results were the same. I also checked this question:
[Profile concurrent CUDA kernels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45889257/profile-concurrent-cuda-kernels)
 and it says that all the concurrent kernels in the application are serialized when profiling, if this is right so why do I get this warning?
here is the kernel call part of the code:

```
cudaProfilerStart();
Kernel <<<BlockNum, ThreadNum>>>();
cudaProfilerStop();
```

Comment: I suggest you re-read the answer you linked to.  It doesn't say what you claim it does.

Comment: For applications that launch a single kernel or that don't have kernels running in parallel, which is probably the case for your code which you haven't shown (the 3 lines you have shown are not sufficient), this message is normal and can be ignored.  It is to be expected that if your application doesn't launch kernels that can run concurrently, you will get this message.  There are other messages that you might see that are also expected, such as "low GPU utilization",   "low compute/copy overlap", etc.  These all depend on your app design, and may be normal/expected for your app.

Answer (score 2):

For the code you have shown:

```
cudaProfilerStart();
Kernel <<<BlockNum, ThreadNum>>>();
cudaProfilerStop();
```

you are only running a single kernel.  It's impossible to observe kernel concurrency with only a single kernel.  To get rid of the  'Low Kernel Concurrency' warning in Nsight profiler, you would need to be running a code that actually launches 2 or more kernels that run concurrently.  Code that only launches a single kernel cannot do this.

If you want to witness kernel concurrency, try running the `concurrentKernels` [CUDA sample code](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#concurrent-kernels).

Regarding this statement in your question:

> I also checked this question: Profile concurrent CUDA kernels and it says that all the concurrent kernels in the application are serialized when profiling

No, that's not what it says, I suggest you re-read it.  Here is what it says in point 1 in the answer:

> 1. Do only tracing. If you don't specify --metrics or --events, nvprof will only do a tracing run. **In this case, nvprof will run the kernels concurrently**, but you will only get kernel timings - not metric/event data.

The profiling facility built into Nsight Eclipse is basically the NVIDIA Visual Profiler - `nvvp`.  With respect to concurrency, it will behave similarly. It can capture and display kernel concurrency in the timeline.  If you select the option to profile concurrent kernels when you start that tool, then for the timeline capture portion, it can show concurrent kernels.  Again, you could use the `concurrentKernels` sample code to try this out.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828962/kepler-concurrent-kernel-launches-not-overlapping/18838920#18838920) is an example of the visual profiler display of kernels that are running concurrently  (and the Nsight Eclipse profiler is basically the visual profiler).